# How to Install Mysql in Kubernetes with GCE

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have tried multiple times to install Mysql with kubernetes 1.8 in Google Container Engine by following the tutorial from [Kubernetes Page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/). The PV, PVC and the Service are created succesfully, but the POD is always giving me error

> PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "mysql-pv-claim" (repeated 3 times)

When I run `kubectl get pvc` it is bounded successfully. I don't know where did I wrong

Here is my deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
selector:
  app: mysql
clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
 ---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: mysql
 strategy:
   type: Recreate
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: mysql
   spec:
    containers:
    - image: mysql:5.6
      name: mysql
      env:
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysql
            key: password
      ports:
      - containerPort: 3306
        name: mysql
      volumeMounts:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
     volumes:
     - name: mysql-persistent-storage
       persistentVolumeClaim:
         claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out that the problem was because the nodes that I used.

I used 3 micro-type server and it failed to give resources to mysql instance and when I upgrade it small or to normal server It works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs you linked:

> You need to either have a dynamic PersistentVolume provisioner with a default StorageClass, or statically provision PersistentVolumes yourself to satisfy the PersistentVolumeClaims used here.

You need to define a default StorageClass for GCE. Something like:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: slow
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  zones: us-central1-a, us-central1-b
```